# Paging in a Microsoft Teams messaging extension search result

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams messaging extension that is returning search results. The documentation mentions paging functionality, but I cannot get this to work:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/search-commands/respond-to-search?tabs=dotnet

I would expect that my search result should be telling Teams that there are additional search results (e.g. a total results parameter) and therefore paging should be available, but I cannot see anywhere that this is set.

As a result, users only see the first page of results.

Comment: Please check FAQPlus app template where they have used pagination - https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/blob/master/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.FAQPlusPlus/Bots/MessagingExtension.cs,  https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/blob/master/Manifest/manifest_sme.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is undocumented, but apparently as long as your return a number of results that is equal to the requested page size Teams will request another page.